# Chrome: not "remembering" the choice to allow access to microphone

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, voice-recognition

I have a super simple web page that uses the [Web Speech API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#introduction) so that I can more easily communicate with my mom (she is deaf). Google's voice recognition is fast enough that I can talk to her in realtime (she reads the vr results).

My site: http://goo.gl/Wm69Mp

We are both using Chrome v30.0.1599.66.

The problem I'm running into is that every time I click on the microphone icon Chrome asks me if I want to allow access.

[image]

I click 'Allow' every time. If I look at Chrome's Media Settings for my site I see that the audio behavior is set to "Ask" but I can't seem to change it to "Allow".

[image]

Does anyone understand what is going on here?

**UPDATE**
It looks like I might have to enable https for my choice to remembered. I'd still like someone to verify that for me if possible.

TIA!
-CS

Comment: According to Googles docs, if you select allow on a `http` URL your preference is not remembered. However if it is a `https` URL it will remember. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?hl=en

Comment: @Paddyd Please change your comment to an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Added it as an answer :)

Comment: @CaymanEss verifiable here - https://www.talater.com/annyang/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Google's Docs](http://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?hl=en), if you select allow on a `http` URL your preference is not remembered. However if it is a `https` URL it will remember.

Comment: But why it does not do same for http://localhost? is it some exception for development purpose?

Comment: Chromium Version 51.0.2704.79 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) does it for https sites too... annoying...

Comment: Same for Chrome 56.0.2924.87 for Ubuntu 14.04.